# :'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.' error

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp, mysql-error-1064

I want to connect to a `MySQl` db using a connection string but unable to connect
I'm using `UWP` and using The fall creator version for both target and min version

I've installed the `Nuget packages` for `Mysql` connector
I've tried to change the string with and without port,ect.

```
public string GetMatchCode()
{        
        string connectString = "Server=###.###.###.###;Database=Db;Uid=root;Pwd=123;sslmode=none;port=3306";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer`";
        using (var connect = new MySqlConnection(connectString))
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connect))
        {             
            connect.Open();
            return command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
}
```

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'
>   MySqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   The error starts at connect.Open();

I've tested the connection with workbench to make sure it's working.
I've looked through most similar post but none have worked for me.

Comment: Please check compare  your  `connectString`  with this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/mysql-databases).

Comment: I did follow that specific document

Comment: But I have not found `user id` parameter in your connect string?

Comment: It's there Uid=root;

Comment: If the MySQl  in your local network please add private networks capability.

Comment: Its on a server not local

Comment: Could you ping your server successful ?

Comment: I could connect with workbench

Comment: I created a code sample and connect to MySQL successful this is my connect string Server=xxxxxxxx;Database=xxx;uid=root;password=xxxxxx;sslmode=none;port=xxxxx.

Comment: What could still be the problem then?

Comment: I think the issue occur in you server, Please check your MySql configuration or update MySql.

Answer (score 0):

There could many possible scenario's where connection will fail.
Please see below points to troubleshoot your error.

> 1. Check your Windows Firewall to ensure that server has an access to   Port's associated with your MySql.
> 2. Disconnect and re-connect your VPN client.
> 3. Follow standard Spacing and Order of parameters in connection string. Follow below format to build/form connection string.
>      `Server=ServerAddress; Port=4563; Database=DataBaseName; Uid=UserName;
>      Pwd=Password;`
> 4. Consider using Connection Pulling, So existing connection will be reused.

Comment: I've tried all those options and even disabled firewall